# Checking if two fields have same value in solr for a document

Tags: solr

I have a huge solr index.I want to find all the documents which have same value in two different fields of a SolrDocument.

Is it possible through solr query?

For example,
if sn1,sn2 are two fields in solr schema. I am interested in finding all results where values in sn1 and sn2 are equal.